# how to calculate tax if checkbox checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox

hi friends i use some inputs with same class and i done the sum and tax calculation with codes but my problem starts when i want to add a feature that if Check box checked it will calculate the tax if not checked it will not calculate it !
this is my code
please help friends

```
<input name="pr-price[]" type="text" class="ad-money ad-price-item" placeholder="price">
<input name="pr-price[]" type="text" class="ad-money ad-price-item" placeholder="price">
<input name="pr-price[]" type="text" class="ad-money ad-price-item" placeholder="price">

<input name="pr-sum" type="text" class="uk-form-width-large ad-money ad-sum-a" value="0">
<input name="pr-discount" type="text" class="uk-form-width-large ad-money ad-discount" value="0">

<input id="ctax" type="checkbox"><label for="ctax">check to count tax</label>
<input name="pr-tax" type="text" class="uk-form-width-large ad-money ad-tax" value="0">
<input name="pr-finalsum" type="text" class="uk-form-width-large ad-money ad-finalsum" value="0">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("change", ".ad-money", function() { 
var sum = 0;
$(".ad-price-item").each(function(){
sum += +$(this).val();
});
$(".ad-sum-a").val(sum);
var sumb = 0;
sumb = sum - $(".ad-discount").val();
var sumc = 0;
tax = .09;
sumc = sum * (1.00 + tax) - sum;
sumcround = Math.round(sumc);
$(".ad-tax").val(sumcround);
var sumfinal = 0;
sumfinal = sumb + sumcround;
$(".ad-finalsum").val(sumfinal);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a condition to check if checkbox is checked, otherwise set tax to 0

```
 if ($("#ctax").is(":checked")) {
     sumc = sum * (1.00 + tax) - sum
 } else {
     sumc = 0;
 }
```

JsFiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/mpsingh2003/5yju8y8f/ 
Let me know if it solves your problem

Comment: tnx my friend it solves my problem but it has a little problem , if we fill one of price fields then check the checkbox it wont work directly and you need to update the price field again with an other value

Comment: Update event handler to capture checkbox event also, Change first line to `$(document).on("change", ".ad-money,#ctax", function () {` I have added checkbox id `#ctax`. Updated JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mpsingh2003/5yju8y8f/1/

Comment: tnx you very much my friend :-*

Answer (score 0):

You can check the state of the checkbox at anypoint of time inside your logic

```
$('ctax').is(':checked')
```

This statement will return a boolean true/false depending on your checkbox checked/unchecked